# Is it right situation to do left outer join?

Tags: sql, join, hive

I have two datatset, A and B.(A is a big dataset like personal info and B is like a small summarized demographic statistic data)
I want to append summary info to A data with demographic info.

As one single row of B can matches with multiple row of A, is it right to send a hive ql like `A left outer join B`?

For example, A is

```
|---------|---------|
|age_range| region  |
|---------|---------|
|14-20    |    1    |
|---------|---------|
|14-20    |    1    |
|---------|---------|
|20-25    |    1    |
|---------|---------|
|20-25    |    2    |
|---------|---------|
```

and B is

```
|---------|--------|--------|
|age_range| region | ratio  |
|---------|--------|--------|
|14-20    |   1    |   0.1  |
|---------|--------|--------|
|20-25    |   1    |   0.2  |
|---------|--------|--------|
```

Comment: Please edit the question and show table definitions with sample data, and expected output.  thanks

Comment: This is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. Show what you are able to do & explain about being stuck, don't ask us to write your code. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; desired & actual output; tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. [ask] [help]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you describe a `join` is appropriate.  If all rows in `a` have a matching row in `b`, then an inner join is sufficient:

```
select . . .
from a join
     b
     on <matching columns>;
```

You would use `left join` when `a` has rows that do not match in `b` *and* you want them in the result set.

Comment: Thanks for your comment:) I edited  the question and specified with an example. As you can see, also there will be some rows that do not match in b. Then is it left join?
To sum up, A has multiple rows that match with one single row of B, but also A has some no match rows with B.

Comment: Left join will work. In the output, you will have all the records from A and common records from B. As, B doesn't have region=2, so for this record in A, output would have NULL in column ratio of the output.